# Microsoft Access VBA 2010 how to create and array of comboboxes?

Tags: arrays, ms-access, combobox, vba

I am new to VBA and Microsoft Access. I have read several posts on this topic but can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Or if I may be missing a reference? I want to add several comboboxes to an array and then reuse that array to do a variety of things like make them visible or not, etc.

The code I have been trying is this - I have tried using Control, AccessObject, ComboBox for the type of arrays and get: Object Variable or with block variable not set -- any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

Dim arrayComboBox(3) As Control

Set arrayComboBox(0) = Me.cmbTourStops1
Set arrayComboBox(1) = Me.cmbTourStops2

arrayComboBox(0).Visible = False
arrayComboBox(1).Visible = True

End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I pasted your code into my own form's module, and changed the *cmbTourStops* names to match mine.  That code ran without error in Access 2010, and it does what I think you intend.  I don't understand why it's throwing an error for you.  Can you share a copy of your database?

Comment: Hi @HansUp I can't seem to access the array value to make changes as described below. Thank you for your post.

Answer (score 0):

Your array of comboboxes should be declared at the form level, i.e. at the top of the module and outside of any subroutine or function. This way it's visible to all the routines in your form code. Also, you can make your routine more general (less dependent on specific control names). See below:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private arrayComboBox() As ComboBox

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim howMany, i As Integer
    Dim ctl As Control
    Dim cbo As ComboBox

    '--- count how many ComboBoxes we have on this form
    howMany = 0
    For Each ctl In Me.Form.Controls
        If ctl.ControlType = acComboBox Then
            howMany = howMany + 1
        End If
    Next ctl

    '--- now properly size the array and store the
    '    controls
    If howMany > 0 Then
        Debug.Print "we found " & howMany & " ComboBoxes on the form"
        ReDim arrayComboBox(1 To howMany) As ComboBox
        i = 1
        For Each ctl In Me.Form.Controls
            If ctl.ControlType = acComboBox Then
                Set arrayComboBox(i) = ctl
                Debug.Print "added " & ctl.Name
            End If
        Next ctl
    End If
End Sub
```